# Azure API Management deploy fails with '##[error]ValidationError: Operation references schema that does not exist.'

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-rm-template

I have some ARM templates for API Management APIs and operations that have worked without any issues before. Suddenly it stopped working even if I have not done any changes to my ARM Template. I get error message:

```
##[error]ValidationError: Operation references schema that does not exist.
```

I always export my API's ARM template using the tool APIManagementARMTemplateCreator.

I think maybe Microsoft has done some changes. Some APIs still work and some does not work. I have tried to understand the difference. One theory is that the APIs that doesn't work have schemas and the ones that work does not use schemas.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a guess because of missing details in your question, but I think you are referencing a retired version in the ARM template:

> On 30 September 2023, all API versions for the Azure API Management service prior to 2021-08-01 will be retired and API calls using those API versions will fail.

[API version retirements (September 2023)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/breaking-changes/api-version-retirement-sep-2023)

Please try a newer version of [Microsoft.ApiManagement service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/service?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template)

e.g. version `2023-03-01-preview`

Sample ARM:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service",
      "apiVersion": "2023-03-01-preview",
      "name": "apim",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Developer",
        "capacity": 1
      },
      "properties": {
        "publisherEmail": "lorem@ipsum.com",
        "publisherName": "lorem ipsum"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It works for another API I have in another Git repository. I have tested with an unretired version. Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

When I removed everything related to schemas in the ARM template it worked. So it has to do with something related to schemas. I still need to understand what has happened.